# Scripting Reverse Boolean

Tags: scripting

So how would I script something that basically duplicated an object and took the last boolean modifier and reversed it while keeping the original modifier order? For example difference to intersect and vice versa?

Answer (score 2):

```
import bpy
context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene

obj = context.object.copy()

bool_mods = [m for m in obj.modifiers if m.type == 'BOOLEAN']

if len(bool_mods):
    mod = bool_mods[-1]
    if mod.operation == 'DIFFERENCE':
        mod.operation = 'INTERSECT'
    elif mod.operation == 'INTERSECT':
        mod.operation = 'DIFFERENCE'

scene.objects.link(obj)
```

Comment: you are the best batfinger! This is exactly what I needed. Also in an understandable format! It works perfectly! Now I am dealing with this silly custom menu icon bs. Its driving me batty haha.

Answer (score 1):

Try this if `x` is the object you want to modify and `copyX` is the modified object:

```
import copy

copyX = copy.copy(x)
last = None

for i, val in enumerate(copyX):
    if type(val) == bool:
        last = i

if last is not None:
    copyX[last] = not copyX[last]
```

Comment: thats an interesting answer that also does the job!